# ¿Como contar las veces que se repite un string en otro string en C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tengo un string, por ejemplo:  `string cadena = "ABABBA";`  y quiero saber cuantas veces se repite la letra **A** junto a la letra **B**, en el ejemplo que puse deberia de dar como resultado **4**.

Tenia pensado usar un for para recorrer el string pero eso funcionaria solo con caracteres.

EDIT:

```
        string frase = "ABABBA";
        string palabra = "AB";
        string palabra2 = "BA";
        string nombre = "";
        int cont = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++)
        {
            char caracter = frase[i];
            nombre = nombre + caracter;

            if (nombre.Contains(palabra) || nombre.Contains(palabra2))
            {
                cont++;
                nombre = "";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Todavía no entiendo... las veces que se cuenta el valor de un `string` en otro o las veces que se cuenta una letra en el `string`?

Comment: @NaCl Lo que quiero hacer es que cuente las veces que la aparezca "AB" o "BA", osea las veces que aparecen la letra A y B juntas sin importar el orden de cual va primero

Comment: @NaCl Error de novato jaja, puse lo que habia intentado en la pregunta, pero yo recorria el string y guardaba caracter por caracter, al final si los cuenta pero como voy creando un nuevo string cuenta "ABA" como 1 sola ocurrencia.

Comment: Está bien asi :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes probar esto:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string cadena = "ABABBA";
int total = Regex.Matches(cadena, "AB").Count + Regex.Matches(cadena, "BA").Count;
```

Te dejo un sandbox funcional: http://rextester.com/YXLKG86994

Comment: Y como funciona `Regex`? Copié y pegué tu código como tal y no me funciona... ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: que error te tira?

Comment: Gracias! me funciono a la perfección, mucho mas fácil de lo que yo intentaba hacer!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: No manches @sodio cualquiera sabe poner "ctrl + ."  hehehe

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara El problema es que estas respuestas no aportan calidad si no se explica el proceso completo para realizar lo que el op quiere, si bien se puede probar esto de arriba, tambien se puede probar otras 1000 soluciones, pero todas deben ir con cada paso necesario para poder ejecutar el código de la respuesta sin problema, ejemplo: en mi caso, yo no uso visual studio, `ctrl + .` no hace nada. ¿Qué me dejas a mí?

Comment: No te lo tomes a mal estimado @Sodio pero a mi me parece una excelente respuesta incluso antes de su edición, ya que a diferencia de otras respuestas que no sabes si funcionan o no, él dejo un link con el ejemplo funcionando correctamente, y de paso ahorró varias lineas a sólo dos, para mi eso es calidad. Te recomiendo que uses Visual Studio, al menos no conozco ningún otro IDE mejor para tecnologías  de Microsoft, pulsa "ctrl + ." sobre el error que tengas y te dirá alguna posible solución, como en este caso te sugerirá aumentar la referencia a "Text.RegularExpressions".

Comment: @Jorge, si quieres que me entere de tus menciones, usa mi seudónimo ;) para eso está. Sé que VS es el IDE para .NET, lo uso pero yo no suelo trabajar en C#, el tema está en que no todo el mundo quiere o puede usar VS y por ende puede terminar en que no tienen idea de que hacer, por otro lado, los enlaces que tienen "la respuesta completa" no son bien bienvenidos, la idea de este sitio es proveer documentación para cuando esos links caigan, no tener que ir a otro link para ver la respuesta completa, saludetes :^)